# Converting a form field to multiple submit buttons?

Tags: forms

I'm not sure how to explain this well in text, but I want to change this:

[image: drupal form field showing 0-5 score]

Into something like this:

[image: 0-5 score buttons]

In Drupal 8, I have an entity for which the only user-editable field is *Score*, which is a **List (integer)** with six possible scores, 0 to 5.

On the edit page, I want users to be able to press a button to assign the score.  There should be one button for each score.

How can I implement something like this?

Comment: I  don't know how to downvote. this question :(.
**to who downvote this question, MR downvoter!**
unfortunately, somebody do not understand here is a place to help other drupal, not a place to see your favorite question.
I'll upvote this question

Comment: here is nice jsfiddle which will help you achieve radio buttons to button like. http://jsfiddle.net/YB8UW/8/

Comment: > I don't know how to downvote. this question : **I don't know who** *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest is, use  hook_form_alter, create an ajax handler on value change on select list, disable ( remove) submit button.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function YOURMODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'YOUR_FORM_ID') {
    $form['YOUR_FIELD_MACHINE_NAME']['#ajax'] = [
        'callback' => array('mycustomSubmit'),
        'wrapper' => 'vote-wrapper'
      ];
    
      $form['YOUR_FIELD_MACHINE_NAME']['#prefix'] = '<div id="vote-wrapper">',
      $form['YOUR_FIELD_MACHINE_NAME']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
    // disable submit button
    $form['actions']['submit']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
 }
}


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function mycustomSubmit(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // YOU CAN DO NODE CREATION HERE, 
    \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage($this->t('YOUR SUCCESSFUL MESSAGE'), 'status', TRUE);
  }
```

and in twig template theme the select options instead of radio, theme them in a button like what you want. ( **or even you can  style radio options as button with just CS**S)

for reference: [Customize Radio Button Appearance with CSS](https://markheath.net/post/customize-radio-button-css)

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.  I want the form to automatically be submitted when a score is selected, but in `myCustomSubmit` you commented about node creation. The node is already created, I just need to save/submit the form. How can I do that?

Comment: @PatrickKenny can you give me more details what do you mean, "already created" have you disabled submit button? how?
can you please add what have you implemented to give more details.

Comment: I disabled the submit button as you suggested in your code. By already created, I mean that the entity is already created, and the form being displayed is the entity edit form for an existing entity; I’m trying to embed the entity edit form and automatically submit it.

Comment: @PatrickKenny what do you expect to be done on node submission? the current node will be updated or create new nodes on each submission?

Comment: I expect the current node to be updated.  I want to show the edit form and let the user update the node.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Yuseferi's example, I was able to come up with the following code.

This completely hides the submit button and automatically submits the form whenever a radio value is changed.

Note that because this form was displayed in a node shown via Views, I needed [the fix described here.](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/295143/formbuilder-getform-outputs-everything-except-the-form-tag-in-a-view)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'YOUR_FORM_ID') {
  
    $form['YOUR_FIELD_MACHINE_NAME']['#prefix'] = '<div id="vote-wrapper">',
    $form['YOUR_FIELD_MACHINE_NAME']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
    $form['YOUR_FIELD_MACHINE_NAME']['widget']['#after_build'] = ['MYMODULE_process_radios'];


    // Hide the submit button.
    $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes'] = ['style' => ['display: none;']];

  }
}

function MYMODULE_process_radios($element, $form_state) {
  $options = array_keys($element['#options']);
  foreach ($options as $values) {
    $element[$values]['#attributes']['onClick'] = ['document.getElementById("MY-FORM-ID").submit();'];
  }
  return $element;
```