# formBuilder()->getForm() outputs everything except the <form> tag in a view?

Tags: 8, views, forms

When displaying my entity edit form with `\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($form);` (for a flagging attached to a node) in a View that is set to show **Content** with the **Default** display, I noticed the `<form>` tag itself is missing:

```
<form class="flagging-myflag-edit-form flagging-form" data-drupal-selector="flagging-myflag-edit-form-iq8dn9lwifq" action="/flag/details/edit/MYFLAG/52" method="post" id="myform-myflag-edit-form--iq8dn9lWIfQ" accept-charset="UTF-8">
Everything between the form tags is printed properly.
</form>
```

The `<form>` tag appears on the node page correctly, but it does not appear in the view.

So somehow, Views is filtering out the `<form>` tag, but I need to keep this tag.

This is the code I am using:

```
function MYMODULE_node_view(array &$build, NodeInterface $node, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
  if ($node->getType() == 'MY_CONTENT_YTPE') {
    if ($display->getComponent('my_flagging_form')) {
      $flag = \Drupal::service('flag')->getFlagById('MY_FLAG');
      $flagging_entity = \Drupal::service('flag')->getFlagging($flag, $node);
      $form = \Drupal::service('entity.manager')
        ->getFormObject('flagging', 'edit')
        ->setEntity($flagging_entity);
      $build['my_flagging_form'] = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($form);
    }
  }
}
```

According to twig debugging, the custom form is being output through `core/modules/system/templates/form.html.twig`, but there's no form tag when output by Views (the tag does appear on the node page).

This is `form.html.twig`:

```
<form{{ attributes }}>
  {{ children }}
</form>
```

EDIT: I tried to render it based on the comment of @Ales:

```
  $form = \Drupal::service('entity.manager')
    ->getFormObject('flagging', 'edit')
    ->setEntity($flagging_entity);
  $form_to_render = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($form);
  $renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');
  $build['remember_form']['#markup'] = $renderer->render($form_to_render);
```

This gives me the same output as my original code; the form is there, but the `<form>` tag is not...

EDIT 2: I also tried using `template_node_preprocess()` instead of `hook_node_view()`:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node__MY_CONTENT_TYPE(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $flag = \Drupal::service('flag')->getFlagById('MY_FLAG');
  $flagging_entity = \Drupal::service('flag')->getFlagging($flag, $node);
  $form = \Drupal::service('entity.manager')
    ->getFormObject('flagging', 'edit')
    ->setEntity($flagging_entity);
  $form_to_render = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($form);
  $variables['MY_FLAG_form'] = $form_to_render;
}
```

But when I rendered this variable in my theme template, I got the same result-- the `<form>` tag appears on the node page, but not in the view that shows Content with mode **full content**.

Comment: hello, you have to render it $renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');
        $myFormHtml = $renderer->render($ \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($form););

Comment: @Ales Thanks for the suggestion, but I just tried that and I didn't get a `<form>` tag that way, either. See my updated question.

Comment: Hm ok. Thanks for letting me know. I came across with another idea. Use render element form https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/264114/83224

Comment: @Ales Thanks.  Digging into this further, I realized the problem is actually caused by views; I had forgotten I was outputting my nodes with Views; when I go directly to the node, the `<form>` tag is rendered correctly.  So the problem is using this code with a view that shows **content** in the **default** view mode.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what the problem could be - I have passed a renderable form array as a variable to node templates a lot and have never ran into this. The one thing I would change personally is using preprocess_node instead of hook_node_view, and in the node template rendering the form array with `{{ myform }}`

Comment: Just noticed you are using an entity form and not a vanilla FormBase form. Views showing the entity content in a view mode should do no filtering of tags, as its just respecting the settings. Did you see this? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/216480/how-do-i-programmatically-generate-an-entity-form

Comment: @Kevin I just tried that and I get the same behavior-- works on the node itself, but not when showing the node in Views. This one has really stumped me.

Comment: could it be that you are rendering this form inside another form? like views exposed filter template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like views reformats rendering as a form if there are any form elements in a row. See `\Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase::elementPreRender`:

```
    // If form fields were found in the view, reformat the view output as a form.
    if ($view->hasFormElements()) {
      .....
    }
```

I guess you should see one `<form>` tag arround the entire view.

In this case a possible solution would be to create a custom views display plugin `Forms`, that overrides the `elementPreRender` method and ignores the form elements check.

Comment: Tip: rendering one form per row might generate a lot of entries in the forms cache table. I would suggest to consider using an ajax link instead for flagging.

Comment: I need to edit the flagging fields on the node page, which is why I'm embedding the form.  Is there a way to disable the caching for this specific form?

Comment: @PatrickKenny I guess `$form['#cache'] = ['max-age' => 0];` should work in `fom_alter`. Bu please double check the problem with the foem caching. It might be fine. I did something similar long time ago with drupal 7.